# Making pit traps more interesting

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, house-rules, traps

I'm currently running the Barrowmaze campaign, which has many 10'x10'x10' pits, often in corridors, so there's no way around them. When reading the campaign, I thought they would be quite interesting, and serve as obstacles the characters would need to come up with creative ways to get over.

After encountering a few pits, I see they are mostly just a minor annoyance to the players. They are only really a danger when unrevealed, when a character can accidently stumble into them. Once they are revealed, they can simply jump across them. Jumping with a 10 ft running start allows characters to jump up to their strength score in feet. Most characters have a strength score of more than 10, so they clear it with ease. Then they throw a rope back across for the one character with a strength of 8.

Some pits are just cubic holes, some have spikes, some of the spike pits are poisoned, and some are bottomless.  In one case, there were two adjacent pits, where one was bottomless. This case was slightly interesting, as they could not jump it. Instead, the druid wild-shaped into a giant spider and climbed along the walls, carrying a rope to make a rope bridge.
Using consumables this way makes the trap something more than just a feature on the map they can easily get across. Using a wild shape and some rope now means it won't be available later. They have to consider if they actually want to cross it.

Are there any other ways I can make pit traps something the players will have to actually think about?

Comment: Hi and welcome to RPG.Stackexchange. Take a look at the [help] and take the [tour]. This is skirting the edge of being opinion based, and we'd really benefit on pinning down what you mean by 'more interesting'. What's the effect you want at the table?

Comment: Not important but a 10 x 10 x 10 ft3 pit is not necessarily 10 ft x 10 ft x 10 ft - so is a 1000 ft x 1 ft x 1ft pit for example.

Answer (score 2):

### Put 2 pits next to each other

Because it’s really funny when they jump the first just to fall into the second. It’s even funnier if the second pit is 100 ft deep.

### Use the pits in conjunction with enemies who like to Shove

For obvious reasons.

### Things live in pits

Green slime, gelatinous cube, skeletons, pit fiends (why else are the called that?) etc.

### Spikes

Rusty ones. With poison.

### [Glyph of Warding](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Glyph%20of%20Warding#content)

With [Reserve Gravity](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Reverse%20Gravity#content) that triggers when they jump the pit.

Or, for an absolute laugh riot, [Wall of Force](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Wall%20of%20Force#h-Wall%20of%20Force) on the far side. Splat. Drop.

### Just remember ...

Evil psychopaths who build dungeons like a laugh as much as the rest of us.

I have always found that *clever* traps are always appreciated by the players ... eventually. I’ve used or encountered all of the above - except the Wall of Force which I will be using as soon as I can

Comment: A stealthy giant constrictor snake at the bottom which reaches out and grapples the first who tries to jump it. Hmmm... Thanks for the suggestions! Especially the Glyph of Warding could have many interesting effects

Comment: Have you tried these things before? How were they received by the party? I’d like to see some subjective experience attached to these ideas.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I have always found that clever traps are always appreciated by the players  ... eventually. I’ve used or encountered all of these - except the Wall of Force which I will be using as soon as I can.

Comment: You should include details about that experience in the answer.

Comment: *Use the pits in conjunction with enemies who like to Shove For obvious reasons*  That's how KorvinStarmast, the Life Cleric, died in game. He got shoved into a pit during a battle with goblins and ogres, and then the baddies came down on top of him an finished him off.  You can add that 'at table' anecdote as support, if you like. PS: wall of force on the other side is brilliant.  Stealing that one ... 